# How to uninstall / update a module from command line odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-11

How can i uninstall / update a module from command line in odoo 11 ? i'm using ubuntu `16.04`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update module navigate to odoo folder which contains odoo-bin file then run command

```
./odoo-bin -u your_module -c /etc/your-odoo.conf
```

To update all module you can use

```
./odoo-bin -u all -c /etc/your-odoo.conf
```

you can also select which database by including -d database_name before -u in command