# Is it normal fields are not updated after installing modules?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm developping a module on OpenERP 7.

It is a very simple code : it has only 1 new field (or column) in python file, and an xpath in the xml. I know it works because one time it was succesfully installed

When I try to install/update my module with the module interface, sometimes the field is added/updated to OpenERP, but sometimes no.

I tried to start/stop and restart Openerp before and after installing my module, but I don't know if it has consequences. I don't have errors or useful thing in the logs.

So fields don't add/update but xml update everytime... Does anyone have an idea of what's going on and a solution ?

python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class StockPickingIn(osv.osv):
    _name = "stock.picking.in"
    _inherit = "stock.picking.in"

    _columns = {
        'adquat_ack_recep': fields.boolean('Accusé de réception'),
    }
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="view_picking_in_form_adquat" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.in.form.adquat</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking.in</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_in_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='stock_journal_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="adquat_ack_recep" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_picking_in_tree_adquat" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.in.tree.adquat</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking.in</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_in_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="after">
                    <field name="adquat_ack_recep" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

I think it works to update fields with Command line -u !

But my other problem is not solved : I dont have empty checkboxes in form view

[image]

And in form view i can't have this checkbox checked :

[image]
I click on edit, i check it and save : the checkbox come back to empty !

I saw in the database the value is saved as true or false, but it's not displayed on the interface

Comment: Are you restarting Odoo instance after updating anything in py files?

Comment: Yes after and before

Comment: Sure i edited the description, but i know it works

Comment: Please add also the XML code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Or you can just show the view where you want to add the field

Comment: i added the xml

Comment: I think you should try with the only _inherit "stock.picking" and add the field in the stock.picking and then inherit picking a view and just add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the following error

> > ValidateError
> >
> > Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!

Because `adquat_ack_recep` is defined in `stock.picking` and you add it to `stock.picking.in` form.

You need to inherit from `stock.picking.in`.

```
_inherit = "stock.picking.in"
```

**Edit:**

Add `adquat_ack_recep` field to both models `stock.picking` and `stock.picking.in` (`stock.picking.in` read method was overitten to read  values from `stock.picking` model). Take a look at [fields not saving problem](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/fields-not-saving-problem-15845)

Comment: Yes I've got this error, but I commented all the xml so see if I've got the field with debug mode, and with debug mode I don't see adquat_ack_recep in the fields of stock.picking.in (stock.picking.in inherit of stock.picking)

Comment: The field should be visible in `Settings -> Technical -> Database structure -> Models -> Incoming Shipments` fields list.

Comment: Ok so I edited my code, i do all inherit from stock_picking_in. It does not work as i want : the field appears in the form view, but if i check it and save : the check disapears (but in the database the value is saved). Other thing in the tree view i don't have any checkbox, when i clic on column i got this error : `ValueError: Sorting field adquat_ack_recep not found on model stock.picking`

Comment: Add `adquat_ack_recep ` field to the both models `stock.picking` and  `stock.picking.in` and see the difference.Take a look at https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/fields-not-saving-problem-15845

Comment: When logging the value of the field from JS we got undefined and after adding the field to the `stock.picking` model, we got the correct value.

Comment: I tried adding `adquat_ack_recep` to stock picking, and `adquat_ack_recep_in` to stock.picking.in. The result is : only  `adquat_ack_recep_in` appears in my fields in the stock_picking_in model

Comment: So i think i should use stock_picking_in. The problem is when i try to sort, the error is *ValueError: Sorting field adquat_ack_recep_in not found on model stock.picking*. That is logic because adquat_ack_recep_in is in stock.picking.in and not stock.picking, but not logic because i'm in the stock.picking.in model.

Comment: I said you the same field in two models, `stock.picking.in` reads fields from `stock.picking`, the method was overridden. take a look at the original code.

Comment: Finally it works with the same name field, i will edit the descripton. Can you write this as an anwser, si i can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem may arises due two instances running at same time. make sure you run single instance. you can also update module through command line this may solve your issue
refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833832/how-to-uninstall-update-a-module-from-command-line-odoo-11/56833953#56833953) for module updation through command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Do you know a way to view running instances ? I have only one window and one tab, but i prefer check

Comment: For the update through command line I know it but I have a problem, we can see later if the problem is not solved with instances

Comment: use command ps aux | grep openerp to get a list of running services

Comment: Please add problem your facing while using update line command

Comment: This is an old machine, i forgot i have to connect in CLI with --db_user and --db_password. Okay so i'm connected i try to update with -u and i tell you ;)

Comment: Btw update with -u works, i can tell you to see my problem in the descrpition or comments with zety